# Spark Memory tuning

Tags: apache-spark, memory, apache-spark-sql, sql-execution-plan

Could anyone let me know how we can tune the spark executor core, memory, num of executors. All the documents which I read about this are derived from the cluster side (https://spoddutur.github.io/spark-notes/distribution_of_executors_cores_and_memory_for_spark_application.html ). But I would like to know how we can tune these parameter related to specific input file.

Eg: I dont want use the same parameter for 1 GB which used for 250 Gb in the same cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an excellent article [here](https://medium.com/expedia-group-tech/part-3-efficient-executor-configuration-for-apache-spark-b4602929262) for choosing right spark parameters.

The goal behind providing extreme importance in configuration of spark executors/cores/memory is to make sure that all resources are fully utilized in an optimal manner to achieve maximum parallelism while processing file(s) of any input size (1 GB, 100 GB, 1 TB).

From the perspective of input file data, one has to make input files partition size correct (By default it is 128 MB) and make sure partitions data  fit in executor memory with no spill (ideal case). Also keep in mind each data partition will be processed by single core in an executor, and so an executor memory should be able to accommodate multiple input partitions (partitions equals to no of cores in an executor) to achieve optimal execution time.

Below parameter will control No of bytes per partition.

```
spark.files.maxPartitionBytes
```